# Why C cannot run this program for large array sizes?

Tags: c

When I run this program for large array sizes (e.g. 100000) the following error appears:
"General Protection" and the run in halted at line 8 (i.e. c[i]=0;).
I wondered if you help me in "How should I modify the following program in order to run"?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
float *c;
void main()
{
long i;
c=(float*) malloc (sizeof(float*)*100000);
for (i=0;i<100000;i++)
    c[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: You need to format your post correctly.

Comment: Have you checked that `malloc` has returned a valid pointer?  i.e. check that `(c != NULL)`.

Comment: You mean: `c = malloc(sizeof(float)*100000)`

Comment: And you really don't want to be repeating your self. You say 100000 twice. You should #define it and so state it only once.

Comment: On most modern compilers sizeof(float*)==sizeof(float). I'm going to guess that you are using a very old compiler, perhaps Turbo C, that is 16 bit.

Comment: I'm allergic to `void main()`.

Comment: @Mehdi What compiler do you have? What is the value of `sizeof(float*)`? Does `malloc` return `NULL`?

Comment: @Mehdi Please please will you just answer the question in the above comment. I realise that you are new to Stack Overflow. Adding information in comments to the answers doesn't help. You need to add more information in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int main(){ 
  float *c = malloc(sizeof(float) * 100000);
  for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
    c[i]=0;

  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I use some C99 features here, and only run for compilers who treats `int` as 32 bit or 64 bit. This should run with gcc on linux or Mac OS X.

Comment: That code is much better, but since `sizeof(float)` is usually <= `sizeof(float*)` it doesn't explain the errors.

Comment: CHECK FOR `NULL` OR FACE MY ETERNAL WRATH!!! (In a silly mood, need sleep, don't judge.)

Comment: have you tested this code? I don't think as variable i will be 100000, because of integer range.

Comment: For modern computer, the int is usually 32bit, its range is from -2147483648 to 2147483647, much bigger than 100000, it is no problem here.

Comment: Unless of course OP is using Turbo C and has 16 bit integers. Which would explain the use of long and the GP fault due to malloc failing to allocate more than 64K.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
c=(float*) malloc (sizeof(float)*100000);
```

Comment: No it shouldn't. Don't cast malloc's return value.

Comment: Won't compile if you don't cast it... what compiler are you using??

Comment: @yi_H - In C++, you must. In C it is optional and many (myself included) recommend against it. If it won't compile you're using a C++ compiler. Use a C++ compiler for C++ code only. The two are not the same.

Comment: @yi_H I'm not using a compiler. You are using a C++ compiler it would appear.

Comment: and I would recommend to cast it so it is portable (without using the extern "C" directive)...

Comment: @yi_H - C code should not be written as C++ code. You don't write Java to be portable to C#.

Comment: looks like a religion debate to me :)

Comment: @yi_H Either you write in C or you write in C++. It's nonsense to think that you can realistically write code that is both.

Comment: I didn't say that. But it can happen that you have a smaller C project which you want to turn into a C++ one. Using a cast for malloc doesn't do any harm, so I still think this is a highly religious debate.

Comment: @yi_H - Anyone who writes Java and expects it to be valid C# is about as boneheaded as some of the more idiotic religious people I've met. (To be fair, I've met some idiotic atheists as well. The fact that I agree with them doesn't make them not idiotic.)

Comment: @yi_H Your argument is specious. When you do turn it into C++ you'll have to change all those casts anyway because you don't use C style casts in C++. In C++ you use C++ casts. And you wouldn't be using malloc anyway, you'd be using an STL container or `new[]`. So if you omit the cast in your C code at least the compiler will find all the places where you need to take action when you port to C++.

Comment: I wouldn't touch malloc/free if it was already working and I don't have to extend functionality associated with that code. Would you?

Comment: @yi_H If you don't want to modify it then leave it in C! You were the one that wanted to port the code to C++!

Comment: I didn't say I don't want to modify it.

Comment: All I have are turbo c++ and borland c++

Comment: Should I install a "c" not c++.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using a 16 bit compiler and that `malloc` can't allocate that much memory in a single contiguous block.

I've just noticed that you are using `long` as your loop variable rather than the more commonly used `int` which further backs up my wild guess.

Comment: I think this is the most plausible answer, coupled with the fact that no check is done on malloc's return value.

Comment: @Skurmedal I think we can be pretty sure that this call to malloc returns `NULL`. It's the only plausible explanation for GP fault.

Comment: yeah :), my point was that the protection fault would go away if a check is done. But it's almost fortunate for the OP this happened so someone could tell him to get a better compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

> float c;

This is a float, not an array. You probably mean:

```
float *c;
```

---

> c=(float) malloc (sizeof(float*)*100000);

This attempts to cast an array of floats as a float. Again, you probably mean:

```
c = (float*) malloc (sizeof(float)*100000);
```

Comment: Please don't cast malloc's return value.

Comment: @David: why not? Just because you don't strictly _have_ to in C doesn't mean that it's not nice to do be explicit about things.

Comment: @Nicol It's better not to. This topic has been covered a gazillion times here on SO.

Comment: @David - While I agree with you, it's still something of a religious issue.

Comment: @Nicol You have been explicit about it when you defined the type of `c`. In fact I'd always prefer using `malloc(N*sizeof(*c))` or even `calloc(N, sizeof(*c))`

Comment: @Mehdi: And what is that error? You said that there was a problem, but you neglected to say what the problem was.

Comment: The error is stated in the question and is General Protection which is what leads me to think the true problem is that OP is using a 16 bit compiler?

Comment: you mean I must use another c language?

Comment: I mean a more recent version of borland c

Comment: And should I install it on 64 bit windows?